# Can a Lombok Builder handle a constructor that may throw an Exception?

Tags: java, exception, builder, lombok

The following does not compile

```
@Builder
public class ExampleClass {
    private final String field1;
    private final int field2;

    private ExampleClass (String field1, int field2) throws JAXBException {
        // all args constructor that might throw an exception
    }
}
```

because of `java: unreported exception javax.xml.bind.JAXBException in default constructor`

The reason for this is probably because the `build()` method does not declare it may throw the checked Exception that the constructor might throw.

Is there a way to let Lombok declare this without explicitly implementing the `build()` method ourselves?

```
@Builder
public class ExampleClass {
    private final String field1;
    private final int field2;

    private ExampleClass(String field1, int field2) throws JAXBException {
        // all args constructor that might throw an exception
    }

    /**
     * I don't want to explicitly declare this
     */
    public static class ExampleClass Builder {
        public ExampleClass build() throws JAXBException {
            return new ExampleClass(field1, field2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you wrap the code in the constructor in a try catch?

Comment: I don't want to wrap the constructor code so that it throws an unchecked exception because I think it's a cleaner contract when it throws the appropriate checked exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder):

> This only works if you haven't written any explicit constructors
>   yourself. If you do have an explicit constructor, put the @Builder annotation on the constructor instead of on the class.

Move the `@Builder` annotation to the constructor and it will work:

```
public class Foo {
    private final String field1;
    private final int field2;

    @Builder
    private Foo(String field1, int field2) throws JAXBException
    {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        throw new JAXBException("a");
    }
}
```

From the documentation

Comment: I did try it, but I accidentally kept the class level annotation as well, which resulted in the same error. Your solution works when putting the `@Builder` annotation only the constructor.

Comment: only when the thrown exception is uncheck/runtime type, i think